# Concatenar en EXECUTE SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

creo este procedimiento almacenado

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Planifiacion_Equipos1
@obra SMALLINT, @fInicio DATETIME, @fTermino DATETIME
AS
DECLARE
@dias nvarchar(400)
SET @dias = ''
SELECT @dias = @dias + '[' + T.dia + '],'
FROM (
SELECT distinct cast ((datepart(dd, freal)) as varchar (150)) AS dia
FROM PlanificacionEQ_realdiario 
) AS T

SET @dias = left (@dias, len(@dias) - 1)

EXECUTE ('SELECT  * FROM VW_Planificacion_Equipos pivot(min(estado)fOR dia in ('+ @dias +'))as pvt WHERE id_obra = '+@obra+'  AND fReal =   '+ @fInicio+' ')
```

pero al momento me da este error cuando a freal en las condiciones del EXECUTE le asigno una fecha ejemplo 02-02-2019 --- Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '2'.

**ACTUALIZACION** 
  Modifique mi EXECUTE dandole dos comillas a finicio

```
  EXECUTE (
 'SELECT  * FROM VW_Planificacion_Equipos pivot(min(estado)fOR dia in (' +
  @dias + '))as pvt WHERE id_obra = ' + @obra + '  AND fReal = ''+@fInicio+'' ')
```

y ahora me lanza este error :
Error de conversión al convertir una cadena de caracteres a datetime.

Comment: Recuerda que el formato de fechas debe ser yyyy-mm-dd. Por ejemplo: 2019-02-02

Comment: lo que yo hago es darle un print en lugar del exec para verificar que este bien la consulta, ya una vez que verifico que esta correcta le coloco el exec

Comment: Cuando realizo un PRINT y ejecuto el procedimiento almacenod este es el error que me arroja Error de conversión al convertir el valor nvarchar 'SELECT  * FROM VW_Planificacion_Equipos pivot(min(estado)fOR dia in ([1],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]))as pvt WHERE id_obra = ' al tipo de datos smallint.

Answer (score 0):

La consulta parece estar en [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server)

Te sugiero estos cambios:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Planifiacion_Equipos1]
@obra SMALLINT, @fInicio DATETIME, @fTermino DATETIME
AS
DECLARE
@dias nvarchar(400)
SET @dias = ''
SELECT @dias = @dias + '[' + T.dia + '],'
FROM (
SELECT distinct cast ((datepart(dd, freal)) as varchar (150)) AS dia
FROM PlanificacionEQ_realdiario 
) AS T

SET @dias = left (@dias, len(@dias) - 1)

declare @sql as nvarchar(max);
select @sql='SELECT  * FROM VW_Planificacion_Equipos pivot(min(estado) for dia in (' +
@dias + ')) as pvt WHERE id_obra = ' + convert(nvarchar(5), @obra) + '  AND fReal = '''+convert(varchar,@fInicio,23)+''' ';

EXECUTE (@sql)

GO
```

Basicamente incluí converts en la consulta que armas para convertir los enteros y fechas a texto.
Creo que puede haber un error en *for dia in (' + @dias + ')*